# How to push to remote repo with GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have to clone a set of projects from one repository and push it then to a remote repository automatically. Therefore i'm using python and the specific module [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Until now i can clone the project with gitpython like this:

```
def main():
  Repo.clone_from(cloneUrl, localRepoPath)
  # Missing: Push the cloned repo to a remote repo.
```

How can i use GitPython to push the cloned repo to a remote repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's all in [the documentation](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#meet-the-repo-type):

```
repo = Repo.clone_from(cloneUrl, localRepopath)
remote = repo.create_remote(remote_name, url=another_url)
remote.push(refspec='{}:{}'.format(local_branch, remote_branch))
```

see also the [push reference API](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.remote.Remote.push). You can avoid the refspec setting if you set a tracking branch for the remote you want to push to.

Comment: This is similar to `subprocess.check_call(['git', 'remote', 'set-url', 'remote', url]`. You can leave out the `url=`, no kw arg needed.

Comment: This is also similar to opening and writing the `.git/config` file and write the stuff within it. Here the OP asks specifically about GitPython ☺. Though, good point for the `url=`, even though the documentation itself uses the keyword in several places.

Answer (score 5):

It should work like this

```
r = Repo.clone_from(cloneUrl, localRepoPath)
r.remotes.origin.push()
```

provided that a tracking branch was setup already.

Otherwise you would set a refspec:

```
r.remotes.origin.push(refspec='master:master')
```

Comment: This solution pushes it to origin, but i wanted to push it to a new remote.

Comment: Does not help because the remote is the same.