# Push to remote repository

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have two repositories on github, using gitpython I'm trying to push a file from one repository to another remote repository. I've managed to do it using git but struggling with the gitpython code.

```
git remote add remote_to_push git@bitbucket...
git fetch remote_to_push
git checkout remote_to_push/master
git add file_to_push
git commit -m "pushing file"
git push remote_to_push HEAD:master
```

I've managed to create a repo object of the remote I think with the following

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo('path/to/other/git/repo')
remote = repo.remotes.origin
```

I can't figure out how to add something to then push, if i call

```
remote.add("file_to_push")
```

Then I get errors about the create() function

```
TypeError: create() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

Trying to follow what they have done in [How to push to remote repo with GitPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429525/how-to-push-to-remote-repo-with-gitpython) with

```
remote.push(refspec='{}:{}'.format(local_branch, remote_branch))
```

I assume it should work with using master and master as the remote branches as they both must exist but it's giving me the error

```
stderr: 'error: src refspec master does not match any.'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
First created a remote of the other repo

```
git remote add remote_to_push git@bitbucket...
```

Then the gitpython code

```
from git import Repo

repo = Repo('path/to/other/git/repo') #create repo object of the other repository
repo.git.checkout('remote_to_push/master') #checkout to a branch linked to the other repo
file = 'path/to/file' #path to file to push
repo.git.add(file) # same as git add file
repo.git.commit(m = "commit message") # same as git commit -m "commit message"
repo.git.push('remote_to_push', 'HEAD:master') # git push remote_to_push HEAD:master
```

Aside from the docs, I found the following to be quite helpful if anyone's struggling with gitpython as I found it quite a pain

[Python Git Module experiences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456269/python-git-module-experiences)

http://sandlininc.com/?p=801

[Git push via GitPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836988/git-push-via-gitpython?rq=1)

[How to push to remote repo with GitPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429525/how-to-push-to-remote-repo-with-gitpython)